# I get UnsupportedClassVersionError while I have the newest Java SE

Tags: java, netbeans, error-handling

I searched hard about this error and I figured out every similar problem was about they have an older version of Java and want to compile with a higher version.

I'm working on a project and one of my partners used the preview feature in a switch case. I got an error but NetBeans (12.0) fixed it by adding `--enable-preview` to compiler options. The error in the code disappeared but when I run the code I got UnsupportedClassVersionError.

1. I downloaded the newest `Java SE 16`.
2. Updated `JAVA_HOME` in environmental variable to `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\` (in path its `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\`).
3. I changed `Source/Binary format` to `JDK 16` in my project properties.

But I still have this problem. Fun fact: if I DONT add `--enable-preview` and run with `run anyways`, it will start and all the implemented functions are working.

How can I solve this without running my code with a false error msg?

Comment: Your problem arises because NetBeans 12 does not support Java 16, which was released more recently. [From the release documentation for NetBeans 12](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb120/nb120.html): _"Apache NetBeans 12.0 runs on the JDK LTS releases 8 and 11, as well as on JDK 14, i.e., the current JDK release at the time of this NetBeans release"_.

Comment: I will try to install the newest version, thank you!

Comment: No! The problem is arising precisely because you are using the newest version. To clarify: [1] NetBeans 12 was released last year, and it supports the JDK version that was current at the time of its release (i.e. 14). [2] JDK 16 was only released a couple of weeks ago, so it's unreasonable to expect NetBeans to support it currently. If you are using NetBeans 12.x, the most recent Java release you can use is JDK 14. [3] If you instead use JDK 15/16/17 with NetBeans 12.x you should expect trouble, because it is an unsupported combination.